# This command can only be run inside of a CLI project

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

For some reasons, I want to use `Angular v5` if I run the below command,it builds an app in `angular 6` which I don't want.

```
ng new hello //this creates angular app in the latest version
```

I ran the command in the below order

```
npm init //generated package.json
```

The above command generated package.json file, I swapped the content of package.json file.

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5acc3c072e164c4a8235152516e44f54

```
npm install //installed all the node modules
```

now when I run command to generate the angular component (or any angular enitity)
it throws the below error.

> This command can only be run inside of a CLI project.

How do I make this app as angular CLI with Angular v5??

Comment: You can try doing ng new hello --skip-install and manually change your package.json

Comment: **npm install @angular/cli@1.7.4** for angular 5 and check **ng - v** for version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can degrade version of `cli` globally `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4`. With this `cli` will generate angular project on version 5.

Or

If you don't want to change your global angular/cli version you can create a new Angular project using `npx @angular/cli@1.7.4 new hello`.

Comment: this will affect the globally angualr cli version right??

Comment: Yes. If you just want to generate Angular app with version 5 you can use `npx @angular/cli@1.7.4 new hello`, then you don't have to change your global angular cli.

Answer (score 0):

Don't degrade version as in Angular 4+ we don't use new to create new component 
Instead use generate command to make new component

> ng generate component your_Comp_Name